# simple wildcard use missunderstanding

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm looking at Wildcards and I understood them in a very simple way.
`<? extends Type>` when I use them just for reading (Returntype) and `<? super Type>` when I'm using It for writing (Parametertype)

```
interface P<T> {
    boolean eval(T e);
}

public class IsZero implements P<Integer> {
    public boolean eval(Integer e) {
        return e.intValue() == 0;
    }
}

public class QQ<T> {
    public void filter(Q<T> q1, Q<T> q2, P<T> p) {
        while (!q2.isEmpty()) {
            T tmp = q2.remove();
            if (p.eval(tmp)) {
                q1.add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, this code given. My professor wrote following solution:

```
/*
Q<? super T> q1 just used as a Parametertype for writing (add)
Q<? extends T> q2 just used as a Returntype for reading (remove)
P<? super T> p just used as Parametertype (eval)
*/
```

I agree with this, but I'll cant figure out why it's `P<? super T>` since eval returns a boolean? Or am I getting the whole Return/Parameter stuff wrong?

Comment: Q<? super T> because q1, q2 and p are allowed to contain subclasses of Integer and not only integer itself... in case of T = Integer.

Comment: Sorry, not subclasses but parents :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p and q1 need to be `Q<? super T>` for the same reason... because both need to be able to **handle** any instance of T and if you are able to handle T or any of its superclasses you are good in that regard. So The reason to set it to `Q<? super T>` instead of `Q<T>` is to make your code as general as it can be.

Another way to put it... if `X > Y` means that X is a superclass/interface of `Y` or `Y` itself and p is `Q<A>`, q1 is `Q<B>` and q2 is `Q<C>`

The the constraints above state that `A > C` and `B > C` regardless what is the relationship between `A` and `B`; if at least one of them is an interface the might not be related at all.

It does not matter whether the method call is going to modify or no the subject.

By the way in most Java standard collections classes `add` also returns a boolean to indicate if the operation changed the collection which is most of the time ignored. So that is not relevant at all.